# How to stop the apache server from timing out while waiting for backend script?

Tags: php, apache, backend

I have a backend script which takes couple of minutes to get executed. I am calling this backend script using a php frontend script. And before waiting for the backend script to be over, the connection times out. I want a persistent backend call so that the front end does not timeout (or times out after a `certain` amount of time).
The error thrown in the console of the web browser is:

    `POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    Object {readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
      custom.js:310
    error custom.js:310
    Connection Timed Out custom.js:310
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434
    POST http:///main.php 504 (Connection Timed Out) jquery-1.8.3.js:8434`

Comment: You could use [`pcntl_fork`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), especially if you don't need the results of the backend script in your frontend

Comment: use max_execution_time

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

```
**void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )**
```

Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the **max_execution_time** value defined in the **php.ini**.

Comment: actually the **max_execution_time** defined in **php.ini** is `max_execution_time = 1200`...still it times out!!
i have even used the `set_time_limit(0);` just before calling my backend...no help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check these PHP functions:

[ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)
and
[set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

```
set_time_limit(0);         //never time out
ignore_user_abort(true);   //ignore abort
```